# How to search for a group where a meta field equals a specific string with bbPress?

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I'm going nuts over this... I need to make bbPress group search to find only those groups where a specific string is inside a meta field.

I tried what I found here: https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/group-meta-queries-usage-example/

I use a different meta field, but tried to implement this as it should be. I can update and read the meta value, but I cannot make the meta_query thing work.

I can see the filter_ajax_querystring function is being executed, because I placed a couple of echo's there to test, and the search term is also there, it only doesn't find the group with the meta key - and it is there.

Anyone who can shed some light? What am I missing?

This is my groups-loop:

```
    $params['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'bp_symbol_code',
            'value'   => $_REQUEST['s'],
            'compare' => '='
        )
    );

    if ( bp_has_groups( bp_ajax_querystring( 'groups' ) . '&' . http_build_query( $params ) ) ) {
        while ( bp_groups() ) {
            bp_the_group();
            // redirect after header definitions - cannot use wp_redirect( $location );
            ?>
               <script type="text/javascript">
               <!--
                  window.location= '<?php echo bp_group_permalink(); ?>';
               //-->
               </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but try  `'value'   => '$_REQUEST["s"]',`. Also put an echo to $_REQUEST['s'] within the function to make sure it's there.

Comment: Opps... you say 'inside a meta field', ie not '='. so you are looking for a LIKE instead?

Comment: but then `'$_REQUEST["s"]'` will be taken literal, also, $_REQUEST['s'] does have the value I'm looking for... any other idea? :)

Comment: sorry, it has to be exactly that string - although I also tried with LIKE and still no luck

Comment: ouch... this is what bp_has_groups() has as argument: Array&per_page=24&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=bp_symbol_code&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=AAAIF&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bcompare%5D=%3D

Comment: Yikes. If you just use ` if ( bp_has_groups( bp_ajax_querystring( 'groups' ) .))` do you get any results? I am afraid I do not know enough about bbpress to be able to help much, hence all the stabs in the dark.

Comment: What I don't get is why even use bp_ajax_querystring? Should it not be simply bp_has_groups('groups')

Comment: beats me, I'm fairly new to bbpress, I'm just recollecting snippets here and there to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I feel stupid....

This was the problem:

```
if ( bp_has_groups( bp_ajax_querystring( 'groups' ) . '&' . http_build_query( $params ) ) )
```

bp_has_groups() was receiving both an array and a query string...

So the solution was just to change the above with this:

```
if ( bp_has_groups( array_merge( bp_ajax_querystring( 'groups' ), $params ) ) )
```

Thanks Gavin, your comments eventually made me realise that mistake :)

Comment: can you please look at this hope you can solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939788/how-set-the-scope-for-the-ajax-query-with-buddy-press-meta-query